# cor function with NA values due to 0 variance

Tags: r

Beginner R user here. I am using the cor function to get the Kendal's tau-b rank correlation coefficient between 2 columns of a dataframe. Examples of such columns are as folows:

```
A    B
1    1
1    2
1    3
```

when I use `cor(d,method="kendall")`

The result is NA for the correlation between A and B. Shouldnt it be 0? And if not is there a way that I can replace this NA result with 0 using a parameter in the cor function?

Comment: If the output is `out` `out[is.na(out)] <- 0`

Comment: Just as a followup. What if I used a dataframe with multiple columns and use cor(d,method="kendall",use="pairwise") is there a way to change all the NA's to 0?

Comment: It would be the same way as `is.na` have methods for `vector` `matrix` and `data.frame` (`methods(is.na)`) and it returns a logical matrix for matrix and data.frame

Comment: Why should it be zero? The standard deviation for `A` is zero and the correlation is not defined.

Comment: You should filter your `d` dataframe to throw away all your constant columns and then use `cor`. There is no merit in treating them `0-correlated` with others. It does not make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what would happen if we slightly perturb the constant column.  We get vastly different solutions depending on the particular perturbation used.  In fact we can get any correlation we like with different perturbations.  As a result it really makes no sense to use any particular value for the correlation and it would be best left as NA.

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1)
y <- 1:3

cor(x + (1:3) * 1e-10, y, method = "spearman")
## [1] 1

cor(x - (1:3) * 1e-10, y, method = "spearman")
## [1] -1
```